# Problem with operator inheritance and cpp core guidelines c.128

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, cpp-core-guidelines

I've following code (I've removed some code not important here):

```
class State {
public:

  virtual void enter() = 0;
  virtual void update() = 0;
  virtual void exit() = 0;
};

class SimpleState : public State {
public:

  SimpleState() = default;
  SimpleState(const SimpleState&) = default;
  SimpleState(SimpleState&&) = default;
  virtual ~SimpleState() = default;

public:

  void enter() override;
  void update() override;
  void exit() override;

public:

  SimpleState& operator=(const SimpleState&) = default;
  SimpleState& operator=(SimpleState&&) = default;
};
```

I've added default operators due to solve a guideline warning since I've defined the destructor and I need to define also other stuff (rule of 5 if I remember).

If I build it with Visual Studio 2019 by enabling cpp core guidelines, I obtain the following warnings:

```
SimpleState.hpp: warning C26456: Operator 'SimpleState::operator=' hides a non-virtual operator 'State::operator=' (c.128).
SimpleState.hpp: warning C26456: Operator 'SimpleState::operator=' hides a non-virtual operator 'State::operator=' (c.128).
```

I want to get rid of it, so I've changed the code in following way:

```
class State {
public:

  virtual void enter() = 0;
  virtual void update() = 0;
  virtual void exit() = 0;

public:

  virtual State& operator=(const State&) = 0;
  virtual State& operator=(State&&) = 0;
};

class SimpleState : public State {
public:

  SimpleState() = default;
  SimpleState(const SimpleState&) = default;
  SimpleState(SimpleState&&) = default;
  virtual ~SimpleState() = default;

public:

  void enter() override;
  void update() override;
  void exit() override;

public:

  SimpleState& operator=(const SimpleState&) override = default;
  SimpleState& operator=(SimpleState&&) override = default;
};
```

But in that case I obtain the following errors:

```
SimpleState.hpp: error C3668: 'SimpleState::operator =': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
SimpleState.hpp: error C3668: 'SimpleState::operator =': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I remove the  guideline warning?

Comment: I suggest you go for [the rule of *zero*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) instead. Let the compiler generate the constructors, destructors and assignment operators for you instead.

Comment: I did it at first and I've obtained another cpp core guidelines warning telling me that a virtual destructor is explicit for a derived class. I've added it and then I've obtained this issue.

Comment: @Jepessen The core guidelines are guidelines, not more. You must evaluate in each case whether a change is necessary or not and you need to read the corresponding section in https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md to determine how and whether to act. Just adding stuff because the warning says so will only make it worse.

Comment: Then please read the first sentence of [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_three) (which applies to the rule of five as well): "If a class requires a user-***defined*** destructor ..." (emphasis mine). If you don't explicitly define (implement) your destructor, you're not breaking the "rule".

Comment: Ok thanks for suggestion. We're starting now to testing the guidelines so we need to elaborate more experience with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the C26456 warning in this case is a bug, see also https://developercommunityapi.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/617702/c26456-false-positive-with-operator-in-derived-cla.html and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/228085/c-core-check-false-positive-c26434.html.

The referenced core guideline clause [C.128](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override) applies only to virtual member functions, but `operator=` is not virtual in your base class and neither does it have the same signature as in the derived class, so there is no reason for it to apply.

---

Make sure that you really want the destructor declaration in `SimpleState`. You have virtual functions in the base class `State`, which seems to indicate that you want to use `State` polymorphically and that objects might be destroyed through `State` pointers, rather than `SimpleState` pointers. In that case `State` needs to have a virtual destructor declared, not `SimpleState`.

If you declare the virtual destructor in `State`, then you won't need to declare any destructor in `SimpleState`, which will inherit the virtual destructor from `State`. Then `SimpleState` can follow the rule-of-zero and wont need any of the copy/move assignment operators and copy/move constructors declared, which is the preferred way.

Comment: That was my original intent. I've added the virtual destructor because cpp core guidelines were complaining about the fact that it was missing, so I've added it and then they were complaining about the rule of 5. So basically I can return to my original code that had implemented rule of zero in `SimpleState`.

Comment: @Jepessen Yes, but don't forget to add `virtual ~State() = default;` to `State`. You may then default the copy/move operations in `State` to satisfy the rule-of-5 for it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in order to override any method, the signature of the overriding method needs to be identical with the original method signature. In your case however, the signature is different `SimpleState& operator=(const SimpleState&)` vs `State& operator=(const State&)`. You are therefore not overriding the original method, but declaring the method as override, hence the error.

Comment: `State& operator=(const State&)` is not virtual in the first place, so it can never be overridden, which is why I suspect the warning to be a bug.